# regex match numbers with potential letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match with JS:

- a number,
- which potentially can be followed by a letter (or two),
- and may be separated by a space
- or hyphen

For example:

```
23 
4545a 
1B 
554 cs
34-S
```

Regex is not my strong suit, so all I've got is this...

```
^[0-9A-Za-z ]+$
```

UPDATED:

```
^(0-9A-Za-z )+$
```

Comment: This is one of the most common regex mixups: when you put a bunch of tokens in a character class (that's the square brackets), you're matching **one** character that's any of those. So `[0-9A-Za-z ]` matches a single character that can be a digit, a letter (upper or lower) or a space.

Comment: The first number, how many digits can it be?

Comment: He has a `+` after the `[]`, which I believe is quite okay

Comment: @lpiepiora No, because now there's no sequence. The space could come first, followed by 16 letters, then 2 digits, followed by more letters.

Comment: Can you give some examples? What can be separated by a space or hyphen? the number from the letters, letters from each other, digits from each other, both? Can you mix and match spaces and hyphens?

Comment: @Asad - sorry, I've misread the question

Comment: @lpiepiora You're misunderstanding what I'm saying. I know that the + applies to the whole character class (which is a single character) and that the order *within* the character class doesn't matter. I'm saying the OP needs the digits to come first, followed by the space or hyphen, followed by the letters, **in that order**. So you can't just say "indefinitely repeat (one character that is drawn from any of these)" and get correct results.

Comment: @santa - your 4th example has 3 letters at the end . . . that's not valid according to your original requirements.  Which is correct?

Comment: @talemyn my bad... fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Aaaaand, mine is a hybrid of the other answers.   :)</s>

```
/^\d+[ -]?[a-z]{0,2}$/i
```

- `\d+` = 1 or more digits
- `[ -]?` = an optional space character (note: space only, not "whitespace") or dash
- `[a-z]{0,2}` = 1 or 2 alpha characters (note: lowercase only at the moment, but keep reading . . .)
- The `i` at the end of the pattern makes it case insensitive, so the `[a-z]` will match upper or lower-case alphas

**EDIT** - Okay, so I found an error in all of our answers.   LOL   Because the alpha pattern allow 0 characters at the end and the space and dash are optional, the regexes that we've provided so far result in a false positive for the following test data: `123-` and `456 <--- with a space at the end`

The second one could be resolved by using `$.trim()` on the value (if that is allowed for what you are trying to test), but the first one can't.

So . . . that brings us to a new regex to handle those situations:

```
/^\d+([ -]?[a-z]{1,2})?$/i
```

- `\d+` = 1 or more digits
- `[ -]?` = an optional space character (note: space only, not "whitespace") or dash
- `[a-z]{1,2}` = must have 1 or 2 alpha characters (note: lowercase only at the moment, but keep reading . . .)
- The `( . . . )?` around those last two patterns enforces that the space or dash is only valid after the numbers, ***IF*** they are, then, followed by the 1 or 2 letters . . . however, that entire group is optional, as a whole.
- The `i` at the end of the pattern makes it case insensitive, so the `[a-z]` will match upper or lower-case alphas

They updated regex matches all of the examples and fails on the two invalid cases that I mentioned, as well.

**Note:** If numbers followed by just a space **should** be considered valid, trimming the value before you test it will allow that case to pass as well.

Comment: We all missed accounting for a couple of "failure cases" . . . have updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 2):

A little verbose perhaps but demonstrates the required parts I think

```
[0-9]+[\s-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}
```

Equates to:

- Any character in the class [0-9], 1 or more repetitions
- Whitespace or a hyphen, 0 and 1 repetitions
- Any character in the class [a-zA-Z], 0 to 2 repetitions.

This regex matches each of your test scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Will following do?

`^[0-9]+( |-)?[A-Za-z]{0,2}$`

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[0-9]+( |-){0,1}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})
```

You can test it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, a very useful tool to test and understand RegEx